# Can we show that $\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2} \leq \frac{1}{n}$

Tags: calculus

Can we show the above or looking at one of the proofs of $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2}$, say using Fourier series, and try to adjust the proof to terms greater than $n$ is the only way? Thanks.

Comment: Riemann sum for $\int_{n+1}^{\infty}\dfrac1{x^2}dx $?

Comment: True, I keep forgetting Riemann sums. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this directly.

**Hint:** $\frac{1}{k^2} \leq \frac{1}{k(k-1)} = \frac{1}{k-1} - \frac{1}{k}$.

Sum up all the terms.

---

If you want a proof via Fourier series, be specific in the question.

---

In fact, we have

$\frac{1}{k^2} \leq \frac{1}{k^2 - \frac{1}{4}} = \frac{1}{k-\frac{1}{2} } - \frac{1}{k + \frac{1}{2}}.$

So we can strengthen the bound to

$$\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2} \leq \frac{1}{n+\frac{1}{2}}.$$

Comment: @Garfield FYI I improved the bound.